# How can I mirror checked items from one CheckedListBox to another?

Tags: vb.net, checklistbox

I have 2 checklistbox controls and want the items in the second control to mirror the checked state of those in the first. For example:

> Checklistbox1 = APPLE, MANGGO, BANANA, STRAWBERRY, GRAPE

Then i checked manggo and grape.

> checklistbox2 = 0,1,0,0,1

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish what you want. Note that if you have a `CheckedListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged` event, you could get unexpected results, as this code will trigger it.

```
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To CheckedListBox2.Items.Count - 1
        CheckedListBox2.SetItemChecked(i, False)
    Next
    For Each i In CheckedListBox1.CheckedIndices
        CheckedListBox2.SetItemChecked(i, True)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large list, this might be a bit more efficient, but you end up with the same result.

```
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To CheckedListBox2.Items.Count - 1
        CheckedListBox2.SetItemChecked(i, CheckedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

Also you might want to have the checkonclick property of your listboxes set to true to save you having to click the item twice - and it yields more consitent results with both my code and the code from @josh , but if you need to do anything else when you're selecting an item, you might want it turned off

Comment: but in checkedlistbox2 no item and in checkedlistbox1 list item from database,

Comment: So you have at the start, a  list of items in checkedlistbox1, but nothing in checkedlistbox2. When you check items in checkedlistbox1, do you want checkedlistbox2 to be populated with just the check status of the items in checkedlistbox1 or the text of all the items in checkedlistbox1? Could you show the code you use to populate checkedlistbox1 please?

Comment: @ant - i dont know if you got notified about the above comment - but if you could let me know your answer, I can look into it more -cheers